# Failed to read from defunct connection (Jupyter notebook, python driver )

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-driver, neo4j-python-driver

I try to import data into a Neo4j VM in Azure.

This code works:

```
def create_article(tx):
    tx.run("CREATE (a:ARTICLE)")

session.read_transaction(create_article)
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
def create_node_article(tx, id, title, label):
    tx.run("CREATE (a:ARTICLE {id:$id, title:$title, label:$label})", id=id, title=title, label=label)

for index, row in df_article_ids.iterrows():
    session.read_transaction(create_node_article, row['id'], row['cleaned_best_title'], row['label'])
```

I have the error:

> Transaction failed and will be retried in 1.0608892687544587s (Failed
> to read from defunct connection Address(host='IP', port=7687)
> (Address(host='IP', port=7687)))

I don't know what I have to change or check. I also tried Neo4j Desktop and I have the same error.

Neo4j version: 4.1.3

Comment: You are using a read_transaction when in reality you are updating the database. Try the write_transaction

Comment: Thank you, can also it be a conflict between the version of the python driver and the neo4j version ?